# nested jquery-ui tabs deeplinking / fragments

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, fragment-identifier

Is it possible to link into a nested jquery ui tab via url fragment?

for example linking to:

**foo.html#tab-1**

is no problem. But linking to:

**foo.html#tab-1-nestedtab-2** (which is a tab content sitting inside the outer tab)

does not work.

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HtrgA/

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I handle this is to trigger the onclick event of the outer tab first, then the inner.

I don't actually use the 'tabs' though.  Instead I hardcode the generated html so I can still use the theming but have fast load times so ymmv.